# How do I do an xpath regex search in my Cucumber / Capybara step definition (Rails 3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, cucumber, paperclip

I have a Scenario that validates that the image I just uploaded exists on the next page.

This below works great, except that I have a variable folder structure based on the listing_id. How can I use regex here to match **image** to only the filename instead of the entire url?

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
    page.should have_xpath("//img[@src=\"/public/images/#{image}\"]")
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `page.should have_xpath("//img[contains(@src, \"#{image}\")]")`, which will match any `img` whose `src` contains your filename.

Comment: I would suggest to rather use `ends-with` function.

Comment: @Jamis: I meant to use `ends-with` XPath function instead of `contains`. I don't know anything about ruby but copy-pasting @dmarkow 's code will give `page.should have_xpath("//img[ends-with(@src, \"#{image}\")]")`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option then using a css selector is more concise in this case:

```
page.should have_selector( :css, "a[href$='#{image}']")
```

Note the '`$`' on then end of '`href$`' to denote matching against the end of the string.